# IOS Google OAuth error occured after 1 success authentication

Tags: ios, oauth

I was trying to make a Google authentication with swift to get message list. However i follow all steps in Google [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)

after i run in simulator and success logging in  to my account authentication was successful. then problem appears after all success which is weird. does any knows how to fix this?

1. selector "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:" is unimplemented or misnamed
2. Assertion failure in void GTMSessionFetcherAssertValidSelector(id  _Nullable __strong, SEL _Nullable, ...)(), /Users/macbookpro/Documents/Zaiya/Pods/GTMSessionFetcher/Source/GTMSessionFetcher.m
3. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'callback selector unimplemented or misnamed'

please share your knowledge, thanks!

actual run error:

[image]

Comment: You need to implement the callback `displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:`

Comment: thanks for response!, would you let me know the actual code? still have the problem

Comment: in the link you posted (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) it already showed the method required bro.

Comment: Hi @haisergeant, thanks for reply, yup it was already there and as stated it successfully run for once after log in, then the following error shows after success. however it still says unimplemented or misnamed the fact that it is not misspelled or unimplemented.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I believe it's because Google hasn't updated the Quickstart for Swift 3 yet.

Change: 
`displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:` to `#selector([Your View Controller Name Here].displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))`, which is in line with the new Swift 3 syntax